# Am I less likely to get a villager if my friend already has them?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In *Animal Crossing: New Leaf*, can the game still give me a certain villager if a friend already has that villager?

For example, I visit a friend's town and they have Benjamin. Is the game less likely to give me my own Benjamin when my friend still has one in his town, to prevent the same villager appearing in two towns at once?

Comment: did any of the two current answers help?

Answer (score 1):

**No**, nothing like this is in the game.

If you have a certain villager, no restriction will be placed on your friends (which of course is true the other way around, too). Multiples of the same villager can, without problem, exist in different towns.

Answer (score 1):

If your friend has a villager in their town, you are more likely to get one of their villagers if they move out of your friend's town at the same time. You can still get new villagers that none of your friends have but you are more likely to get one that they do have.

Comment: I'd like to add that one of their villagers moving out is not a coincidence. If you visit a friend's town, you will automatically "trade villagers", meaning that one of your villagers and one of your friend's will start moving out, and will eventually move to the other's town.

Answer (score 0):

**Of course not**! Allow me to explain with a little life story:

In my town, a humble little bear-creature named **Clay** resides near the beach cliff in my town. Meanwhile, in my little brother's town in *Animal Crossing: New Leaf,* **Clay** ALSO resides in his town, but by the train station. If you search any character residing in your town on [Google](http://www.google.com), you will also see many other people have that same character in their town. Long story short, nothing restricts a certain villager from living in a certain town. All is random.

I hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are actually more likely to get a villager from a friends town if one of theirs moves out and you don't have the maximum amount of villagers. It happened to me so this is 100% true.